# SQL Sserver : two column have same value in different order and want only distinct combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this in SQL Server

```
src     destination
-------------------
A               B
B               A
A               D
D               A
B               D
D               B
```

I want result like this

```
src     destination
-------------------
A               B
A               D
B               D
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've solution on page level but not getting the solution on query level.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to accomplish this.  Probably the best performing is `union all` with `not exists`:

```
select src, dest
from table t
where src < dest
union all
select dest, src
from table t
where dest > src and
      not exists (select 1 from table t2 where t.src = t2.dest and t.dest = t2.src);
```

Note:  this assumes that you have no duplicates in your data (as is the case with the sample data).

Comment: This will duplicate items that do not have a reversed record.  Example:  `Insert Table Values ('A', 'C')` without a `C | A` counterpart, and it will list both `A | C` and `C | A` as a result.

Comment: @Siyual . . . If there is no reversed record, then this cannot produce both (A, C) and (C, A).  Note the `dest > src` in the second subquery.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on Gordon's answer, this may be a better solution.  Gordon's answer will not catch cases where the `src` and `destination` are the same value, and it will also lead to duplicated results where there is no reversed counterpart.  This should work better:

```
Select  A.src, A.destination
From    Table   A
Join    Table   B   On  A.src = B.destination
                    And A.destination = B.src
Where   A.src < B.src

Union

Select  src, destination
From    Table
Where   src = destination

Union

Select  src, destination
From    Table   A
Where   Not Exists 
(
    Select  *
    From    Table   B
    Where   A.src = B.destination
    And     A.destination = B.src
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, this was old post but my answer may help someone who is looking for solution around the similar problem.

Here, with the help of case statement we can remove duplicates on two columns

```
select distinct 
case when "src" < "destination" then "src" else "destination" END as src, 
case when "src" < "destination" then "destination" else "src" END as destination
from trip
```

Sql Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c2d17/1